# Variable class from library

Tags: php, object-oriented, php5

Can I do something better with this code?  It's just a snippet of a library I wrote.

```
<?php
/*
 * Variable.class.php
 * (c) 2013 sinan eker`enter code here`
 * */
 class Variable extends Config {
     protected static $vars = array();
     final public static function variables(){
         return static::$vars;
     }
     final public static function clear(String $name){
         unset(static::$vars[$name->getString()]);
     }
     final public static function destruct(){
         unset(static::$vars);
         static::$vars = array();
     }
     final public static function override(String $name, $value){
         static::clear($name);
         static::register($name, $value);
     }
     final public static function get(String $name){
         $name = $name->getString();
         return (isset(static::$vars[$name]) ? static::$vars[$name] : null);
     }
     final public static function register(String $name, $value){
         return (!is_null(static::get($name)) ? false : static::$vars[$name->getString()] = $value);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, method and variable docblocks are recommended. Provide a description of each method, its parameters and their return values.

I would give your getter function `Variable::variables()` an active name like `getVariables()` and rename your `Variable::get()` method to `getVariable()`. Consistency is important and you want to avoid confusion with the magic getter [`__get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php).

Are you intentionally using the non-magic method `Variable::destruct` instead of the PHP magic method [`__destruct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)?

This is more of a syntax preference, but I would use `array_key_exists()` instead of `isset()` when referring to the property `static::$vars` since I find the verbage more aligned with what you are testing.

The docblocks are the only important thing. Good work.

Comment: First of all, thank you! I would not use array_key_exists, isset is faster!

Comment: also this is a class, for using without an object instance. so the static is entitled!